# what does the following code do in C?

Tags: c, pointers, while-loop

I saw the following code from somewhere:

```
while(*i++ = *j++)
{
}
```

but what is this code doing? what is the meaning of it?

Comment: That depends on what `i` and `j` are...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely, if i and j are char*, then it copyes null-terminated string j into memory that starts at i.
You might wanna keep in mind that i and j itself changes (`i += strlen(j)`) so code above also breaks the pointers to a strings.

Answer (score 4):

It copies elements from an array (or a pointer to an array) called `j` to one called `i`.  It does this until it finds a value (from `j`) which is equivalent to zero.

This is a common idiom for copying C-style, null-terminated strings; it could also be used to copy an array of integers terminated by a sentinel zero.

In case the size of `j` can be known in advance, it might be better to use `memcpy()`.  And in case the size of `j` cannot be known in advance, it is likely the code is unsafe, because the proper size to allocate for `i` cannot be known either.

Answer (score 2):

It copies the data pointed to by j, to the array pointed to by i, and continues until a value of 0 has been copied. It is perhaps used to copy a null-terminated string. To be even more clever, you can use

```
while(*i++ = *j++);
```

Comment: 2 compiler warnings and 6 MISRA violations for one single line of code. How exactly does that count as clever?

Comment: Because of the trailing semi colon. Programmers who don't like surprises or compiler warnings write such as `while(*i++ = *j++) <new line here> 
  ;`, to demonstrate to the reader that the semicolon wasn't just an accidental slip. C programmers are very trigger-happy when it comes to writing accidental semi-colons at the end of lines;

Comment: Btw `while((*i++=(*j++??!0))!='??/0')??<??>` is far, far more clever. We should all use that snippet from now on, when copying strings.

Comment: @Lundin That makes it more complicated, not less.

Comment: I believe I was being sarcastic over what's clever and what is not.

Answer (score 1):

*j++ derefrences the pointer, increments its value.

*i++ = *j++ assigns the old value of *j to *i, then *i++ increments this value and saves it for use the next time

```
while(*i++ = *j++)
```

is executed.

---

**If i and j are char[], then**

```
while(*i++ = *j++)
```

***is copying characters from j[] to i[]*** until NULL character is reached.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers, `while(*i++ = *j++){}` is a less readable, more compact and more dangerous way of writing

```
*i = *j;

while(*i != 0)
{
  i++;
  j++;
  *i = *j;
}
```

The two cases will generate *exactly the same machine code*.

Comment: As a side note, `while(*i++ = *j++){}` generates no less than 5 MISRA violations. Very impressive for a single line of code.

Comment: Is anybody outside the automotive industry concerned about MISRA? Besides, your code is not equivalent. You are pre-incrementing.

Comment: @undur_gongor That depends. Is anybody outside the automotive industry concerned about writing bug-free, readable, maintainable programs? I'm not sure. If they are, they should definitely adhere to MISRA. And the code is not pre-incrementing, please note the initial assignment. (I'd actually prefer use a do-while instead of this but beginners often consider that harder to read.) So the loop actually goes: copy, check against zero, increment both operands.

Comment: You are right wrt. the pre-increment. Of course. Regarding MISRA, it's interesting to see a SW developer actually recommending it.

Answer (score 0):

It primarily depends on what `i` and `j` are. One case can as be follows.

Assume that `i` and `j` are two pointers to a character string, then the value of `i` and `j` will get simultaneously increased, and assign the value of `*j` as `*i`, whenever the value of `j` becomes `0` ie, `\0` the loop will exit after assigning that `0` to *i.

Obviously this can be used to copy the content of `j` to `i`.